# Showing value as percentage incorrectly in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, unique-values

I have added a table to my power BI dashboard and my accuracy column showing results as percentage of grand total.But as the image the percentage is showing incorrectly and my measure is correctly done.when i set the values as no calculation is shows values correctly.but when i set values as show percent of grand total its appearing incorrectly.Is there a way to solve this? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: And what are the expected correct values in this case?

Comment: Can you share a bunch of sample data and your current DAX formula?

Comment: I have results from the measure as 1.00 and 0.90 .so i want to display this values as a percentage.so 1.00 should be 100% and 0.90 should be 90%. but it shows as this when i set this value as percent of grand total.I have added another image on the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use FORMAT function to show your value as percentage

Lastweek % = FORMAT([Accuracy Last Week],"0.00%")

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dax Divide for result of percent for Column

for example

```
PercentDifference= DIVIDE('Query1'[SALES]; Query1[budget])
```

Comment: i already used this dax for my measure.My values are correct.but when i change the value to percentage it shows like this.